# Using enviroment variables in JSON file

Tags: typescript, environment-variables

I'm looking for how to use `.env` at `.json`. Because the `ormconfig.json` is where we configure our database, like username, password and etc... And I would like to know if it's possible to use .env in json.

Comment: JSON does not have notion of environment variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in JSON it is not possibile. Just transform your `ormconfig.json` to `ormconfig.js` and use the following:

```js
module.exports = {
  // Your previous JSON configuration
}
```

This will works just the same as before, but you'll get access to `process.env`, like:

```js
module.exports = {
  url: process.env.URL,
  // ... other options
}
```

Answer (score 1):

But, you can try this way by creating `.js` and exporting it as object:

```
module.exports = {config: {"userName":"sam123"}}
```

Then:  Stringifying the object and then, Parsing it back to JSON.

```
const config = require("./jsExample.js").config;

const jsonConfig = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(config))
```